# ClosedXML export column header to excel [C#]

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export, closedxml

I have a function to export datagridview to excel using CloedXML. Everything works ok, BUT:

I add columns from datagridview to datatable using

```
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvLoadAll.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(column.Name);
            }
```

This uses column.Name which is Design (Name) in my dgv. I want to add column.HeaderText. When I use

```
            dt.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, typeof(string));
```

it adds column headers sucessfully, but export does not work ok. It only exports columns where there are no special characters or even blank char. ("Name" column is exported, but "IUPAC Name", or "Čas" is not, ...). Renaming is not an option.

Here is the part of export function responsible for writing cells. Just reminder: It works 100% OK when I use column.Name.

```
            foreach (int rowindex in rowsselected)
            { 
                foreach (int columnindex in columnsList)
                {                    
                        worksheet.Cell(k+2, j+1).Value = dt.Rows[rowindex] [columnindex].ToString();
                        j++;
                }
              j = 0;
              k++;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like on MSDN for [`DataColumnCollection.Add(string columnName, Type type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and in their [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `columnName` is for setting the *variable name* of the new DataColumn. That means you are limited to valid variable names as input, which would explain why spaces and special characters do not work. I would imagine that `_Name`, `Address1`, `Zip_Code`, etc. would work.

Also, I couldn't tell from your example, but I think you may be misunderstanding what the `type` parameter is for. It is for setting the *variable type* that the `DataColumn` holds. You do not need to specify `typeof(string)` because the default type of a `DataColumn` is `string`.

Comment: that typeof(string) was just a shot..I get it now..

I don't know if I explained the situation well. My code adds columm headers to excel. But exporting rows is broken. It only exports values "under" columns with no special char or spaces.

this is my function to write rows to excel:

foreach (int columnindex in columnsList)
                {
                    worksheet.Cell(1, col_).Value = dt.Columns[columnindex].ToString();
col_++;
}